# TV show about someone who could control time with a belt

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, tv

I can't remember the title but it was a television show, late 60s early 70s about someone, a male character, who could control time with a belt.  It wasn't Dr. Who. And it was on CBS, I believe.

Comment: What else can you remember? There's a checklist here to help you out; https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question

Comment: Who was the someone who could control time (man, woman, alien?). What was their name? How did the belt work (did it have a button or a dial)? Was the show American? Were there any baddies? What problems did they solve with this belt? Was there a love-interest?

Comment: http://www.timebelt.net/index.shtml

Comment: @Mithrandir - Best show ever. I heard they were planning to remake it with a GoT sized budget

Comment: TV show or film? https://youtu.be/6EimxJAcoU8?t=24m19s

Comment: It was a male character

Comment: It had a better budget.  And was i belive cbs

Comment: There was a love intrest.

Comment: I was originally thinking _[Voyagers!](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyagers!)_ but that came a bit later and was on NBC.

Comment: The charecter was male. It was more like a pilot t

Comment: Belt user was male was serious and i belive that he had stolen the belt. The belt had a dial and buttons to the best of my recolection. And it was an american program

Comment: Do any of these details (suggested by a non-answer) ring any bells? "I believe it was a team and the main chr was an un authorised user. They could go through unlocked doors unseen. (So fast you couldn't see them)."